# Calculate a p-value for SVM-plots on Iris dataset (2D-data)

Tags: svm, python, p-value, matplotlib

I analyzed the Iris dataset by using the Python libraries: Matplotlib, seaborn, sklearn and mlxtend. An example of a plot is shown :

[image]

and my code is :

```
def create_svm_plot(value1, value2, shape):

    from sklearn import svm
    from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
    # First, we'll import pandas, a data processing and CSV file I/O library
    import pandas as pd
    # We'll also import seaborn, a Python graphing library
    import warnings # current version of seaborn generates a bunch of 
    warnings that we'll ignore
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    X = iris[[value1, value2]]
    y = iris['SpecieID']

    plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))

    if shape == "round":
        clf = svm.SVC(decision_function_shape = 'ovo')
    elif shape == "linear":
        clf = svm.SVC(C=0.5, kernel='linear')
    else:
        raise NameError('Shape must be round of linear')
    clf.fit(X.values, y.values) 

    # Plot Decision Region using mlxtend's awesome plotting function
    plot_decision_regions(X=X.values, 
                          y=y.values,
                          clf=clf)

    # Update plot object with X/Y axis labels and Figure Title
    plt.xlabel(X.columns[0], size=14)
    plt.ylabel(X.columns[1], size=14)
    plt.title('SVM Decision Region Boundary : ' + value1 + " and " + value2, size=16)

    legend = plt.legend()
    legend.get_texts()[0].set_text('Iris-setosa')
    legend.get_texts()[1].set_text('Iris-versicolor')
    legend.get_texts()[2].set_text('Iris-virginica')

create_svm_plot('SepalLengthCm', 'SepalWidthCm', "linear")
```

My question is : is there any way to calculate a p-value for this plots?
I also made a 1D SVM plot and I used an ANOVA test to calculate the p-value of the three groups. But in this case the data is 2D and divided in three groups, so I am trying to find a way to calculate the p-value for this data.

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about the hypothesis test for which you want to calculate the P-value?

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic because it's not clear what it means to compute a p-value for a **plot**.

Answer (score -1):

SVM from sklearn has an additional input argument: probability=True:

*probability : boolean, optional (default=False)
Whether to enable probability estimates. This must be enabled prior to calling fit, and will slow down that method.*

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html

Note that the interpretation of these probabilities differs from that of  frequentist statistics (p-values). The returned probabilities are estimates of posterior probabilities, i.e. probabilities for a particular iris species given the features (e.g. sepal widths and lengths).

Comment: Minor edits to last para in wording. Please check that your intended meaning is matched.